# AsyncTask and Sockets not going off

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, android-asynctask

Before you mark this as duplicate please hear me out. I have taken previous advice from members of StackOverflow and I still cannot get this to work but I have improved my code and bottled down to what could be the problem but I do not understand what it is I am doing wrong. FYI: This is the client-end of clients-server chat program I am making. I have made the PC version of the server and client that is FULLY functioning.

On to what I believe might be the source of problem. If you look at the ServerTask class (executed when connect button is pressed), it looks like it's not starting the socket? Could someone please help me out extensively? Will be incredibly grateful if someone can help this hopeless beginner.

This might not help but here is also AndroidManifest.xml because I saw somewhere I need to set permissions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.JurkoAndroidChat"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>




package com.example.JurkoAndroidChat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    // Right here, we connecting the components of the main.xml form to code
    Button connectButton, disconnectButton, sendButton;
    TextView chatArea, clientArea;
    EditText messageField, usernameField, ipField;

    //Extra variables and sockets
    String username, serverIP;
    int Port = 5000;
    Socket sock;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    ArrayList<String> userList;
    Boolean isConnected = false;
    ServerTask serverTask;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Working?");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        userList = new ArrayList();
        connectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        sendButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        disconnectButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        chatArea = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        clientArea = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        messageField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ipField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);



        connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                if (isConnected == false) {
                    username = usernameField.getText().toString();
                    usernameField.setFocusable(false);
                    usernameField.setClickable(false);
                    serverIP = ipField.getText().toString();
                    ipField.setFocusable(false);
                    ipField.setClickable(false);
                    serverTask = new ServerTask();
                    serverTask.execute();


                } else if (isConnected == true) {
                    chatArea.append("You are already connected to the server.\n");
                }
            }
        });

        disconnectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                String bye = (username + ": :Disconnect");
                try {
                    out.print(bye);
                    out.flush();
                    chatArea.append("Disconnected.\n");
                    sock.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                isConnected = false;
                usernameField.setFocusable(true);
                usernameField.setClickable(true);
                ipField.setFocusable(true);
                ipField.setClickable(true);
                clientArea.setText("");
            }
        });

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
                String nothing = "";
                if ((messageField.getText().toString().equals(nothing))) {
                    messageField.setText("");
                    messageField.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    try {
                        out.println(username + ":" + messageField.getText().toString() + ":" + "Chat");
                        out.flush();
                        serverTask.printToStream("hey");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        chatArea.append("Message was not sent.\n" + e);
                    }
                    messageField.setText("");
                    messageField.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });


    }

    public class ServerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                Log.i("Asynctask", "doInBackground");
                sock = new Socket(serverIP, Port);
                out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
                out.println(username + ":" + "has connected." + ":" + "Connect");
                out.flush();
                isConnected = true;

            } catch (Exception ex) {
//                    chatArea.append("Unable to connect to " + serverIP + " at port " + Port + "." + ex);
//                    ex.printStackTrace();
//                    usernameField.setFocusable(true);
//                    usernameField.setClickable(true);
//                    ipField.setFocusable(true);
//                    ipField.setClickable(true);

            }
                new streamTask().execute();
            return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        public void printToStream(String message) {
            try {
                out.println(message);
                out.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {chatArea.append(e + "\n"); }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
           //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    }

    public class streamTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String[] data;
            String stream, done = "Done", connect = "Connect", disconnect = "Disconnect", chat = "Chat";

            try {
                while ((stream = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    data = stream.split(":");

                    if (data[2].equals(chat)) {
                        chatArea.append(data[0] + ": " + data[1] + '\n');
                    } else if (data[2].equals(connect)) {
                        chatArea.setText("");
                        userAdd(data[0]);
                    } else if (data[2].equals(disconnect)) {
                        userRemove(data[0]);
                    } else if (data[2].equals(done)) {
                        clientArea.setText("");
                        writeUsers();
                        userList.clear();
                    }


                }
            }  catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

    public void executeTask() {
        new ServerTask().execute();
    }

    public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

        }
    }

    public void ListenThread() {
        Thread IncomingReader = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
        IncomingReader.start();
    }



    public void userAdd(String data) {
        userList.add(data);
    }

    public void userRemove(String data) {
        chatArea.append(data + " has disconnected from the server.\n");
        for (String token:userList)
            if (token.equals(data))
                userList.remove(token);
    }

    public void writeUsers() {
        String[] tempList = new String[(userList.size())];
        userList.toArray(tempList);
        for (String token:tempList) {
            clientArea.append(token + '\n');
        }
    }








}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly is your problem since there is no logs (I suggest you provide the log so that we can help you), but when I go through your code, I can see there is one big issue:
**you tried to update the UI in a background thread** 
See those lines of code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String[] data;
            String stream, done = "Done", connect = "Connect", disconnect = "Disconnect", chat = "Chat";

            try {
                while ((stream = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    data = stream.split(":");

                    if (data[2].equals(chat)) {
                        chatArea.append(data[0] + ": " + data[1] + '\n');
                    } else if (data[2].equals(connect)) {
                        chatArea.setText("");
                        userAdd(data[0]);
                    } else if (data[2].equals(disconnect)) {
                        userRemove(data[0]);
                    } else if (data[2].equals(done)) {
                        clientArea.setText("");
                        writeUsers();
                        userList.clear();
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null; // To change body of implemented methods use File |
                            // Settings | File Templates.
        }
```

There are some places that you update the UI in this doInBackground which executes in a background thread, and will lead to exception.
Read this article, that might help https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: ^ I've been so caught up on this error first, I totally forgot about my second AsyncTask but if you see, I commented out the body of my catch statement because it was crashing my app (I already knew about this updating UI on the AsyncTask ;) ). Heres an update though.  ERROR/Application(9566): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 5000): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: I am running this on a physical device. So localhost still turns out to be 127.0.0.1. I am running the client on my PC no problem. I port forwarded and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Going to leave this here for everyone having troubles with AsyncTask as it may sound confusing, it actually works. I finally got it to work, I don't know why localhost wasn't working as it was a physical device I was testing on (Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0). I decided to try my actual external IP and it finally worked.

Build your app so the physical network stuff (no GUI) is done in    doInBackground Still getting the UI stuff done but I believe it can    be done through runOnUIThread or in the same task but in    onPostExecute